# Rotate all objects around world origin

Tags: transforms

I wish to rotate everything around the world origin by 90 around Z axis, thus effectively swapping X and Y axes. When I select everything and rotate, all objects get rotated around their local axes. I'm new to blender and I have no idea if there's an option to change this behavior. Can I somehow swap X and Y?

Comment: At the top of your screen, in the middle of the top, you can see the word, default there is the word "Global" in this part of the blender you can change what alignment is used and what is midpoint of rotation, If you want to rotate around world origin, you should place 3d cursor in the world origin and rotate around 3d cursor

Comment: [Blender Manual - Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is you want to rotate around world origin, you can snap your 3D cursor to the world origin (Shortcut SHIFT+S --> World origin or shortcut SHIFT+C)
[image: cursor to world origin]

Then select all the object you wish to rotate, and select the 3D cursor as transform pivot [image: Transform Pivot 3D Cursor]

And to rotate, you just press R and typing 90 on your numpad, or using the rotate gizmo.

[image: Rotate by 90°]

Comment: Thanks! I seems to work.